# How to properly import datetime module into a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import `datetime` module, which I use to create functions to be applied over a `pandas` dataframe column:

Here's the code so far:

```
### importing modules ###

import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import dateutil.relativedelta


### function to return last day of month date ###

def last_day_of_month(date):
    if date.month == 12:
        return date.replace(day=31)
    return date.replace(month=date.month+1, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

### function to return a date difference ###

def set_data_loa(data_de_retorno):
    if pd.isnull(data_de_retorno):
        d1 = datetime.now()
        d2 = d1 - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
        return last_day_of_month(d2)
    else:
        return data_de_retorno


###################### applying over datetime64 type pandas df column  ##############

input_1['data_para_loa'] = [set_data_loa(data_de_retorno) for data_de_retorno in input_1['data_de_retorno']]
```

The next error arises

> AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

I am running this code in a Jupyter Notebook IDE,

What am I missing?
How could I properly import `datetime` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've imported `timedelta` from `datetime`. So you need to reference it as `timedelta`, not as `datetime.timedelta`. Just like you can't reference `date` as `datetime.date` in this example because you imported `date` from `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `from some_package import some_function` you no longer need to prepend the function with the package name using dot syntax, e.g.:

```py
from random import choice
choice("ABCD")
```

vs

```py
import random
random.choice("ABCD")
```